# MariaDB: Select the fields from one column in one table that are not in a subset of another column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

**Update**: Do not provide an answer that uses `NOT EXISTS`. According to [MariaDB](http://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/exists.php) "SQL statements that use the EXISTS condition in MariaDB are very inefficient since the sub-query is RE-RUN for EVERY row in the outer query's table." This query will be used ***a lot***, so it needs to be efficient.

I have two tables `following`:

```
CREATE TABLE `following` (
 `follower` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `followee` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`follower`,`followee`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and `association_record`:

```
CREATE TABLE `association_record` (
 `user_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `post_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `answer_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

What I want are the `follower`s of `followee` '5' who do not have an `association_record` with post '88'. The below SQL is what I came up with from reading other posts, but it doesn't get me the desired results:

```
select f.follower
from following f
left outer join association_record a
on f.follower = a.user_id
where f.followee = 5
and a.post_id = 88
and a.user_id is null
```

Comment: " users who are following the user with id '5' who do not have an association_record for the post with id '88' " ???  The sentence first noun "users", do you mean "follower" instead of users?

Comment: I just rephrase your question. I think you should spot the problem of your question.  Did changing last statement to  "f.follower is null"  fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the query that did it:

```
SELECT f.follower
FROM following f
LEFT OUTER JOIN association_record a
ON f.follower = a.user_id
AND a.poll_id = 88
WHERE f.followee = 5
AND a.user_id is null
```

Forgot to post the solution to my question after I solved it, and now a month later, I end up having a similar problem but without any reference to the original solution; didn't need it anymore.

Almost had to resolve the whole issue again from scratch; which would have been tough being that I never understood how the solution worked. Luckily, MySQL workbench keeps a log of all the queries ran from it, and trying queries to answer this question was one of the few times I've used it.

Moral of the story, don't forget to post your solution; you might be doing it for yourself.

Comment: @mhyst here is the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.follower from following f, response_record r where f.follower = r.user_id and f.followee = 5 and r.post_id = 88 and r.user_id is null
```

try this

Comment: nope, doesn't work either. it seems like it's just the same thing as my sql though

Comment: doesn't return any records; even with <> '88'

Comment: i don't see why it would be <> '88' anyways. what i want are the users who don't have an association_record _for_ post '88'. not the users who don't have an association_record for every post other than '88'

Answer (score 0):

To make things easier, it is better to start step by step.

So, we need people who follows user '5'? Here is the query.

```
select follower from following where followee = 5;
```

Now we need to know wich users have a record on post '88'.

```
select user_id from association_record where post_id=88;
```

Now we need fixing both queries in some way. Let's do it:

```
select follower from following where followee = 5 and not exists (select user_id from association_record where post_id=88 and user_id=follower);
```

And that's it. Here you have your query explained.

Comment: getting these three errors in phpmyadmin 1. Unrecognized keyword. (near "not" at position 54) 2. Unrecognized keyword. (near "exists" at position 58) 3. Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 65)

Comment: copied it verbatim. there are red wavy lines underneath not, exists, and select. no idea why

Comment: I have checked that "not exists" should work with MariaDB. Take a look by yourself http://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/exists.php

Comment: Try using NOT IN instead and remove "and user_id=follower" part.

Comment: I get user_id and follower are correspondent? Isn't it?

Comment: still saying i have an error in my sql syntax. did exactly as you said. here is my query: `select f.follower from following f where not in (select a.user_id from association_record a where a.post_id=88)`. there's no specific error. it just says it's near `in`

Comment: in that link it emphasizes that using exists is very inefficient. know how to do this using joins?

Comment: I don't know exactly MariaDB, but aliases can be made as "following f"? Remove the "f" and remove "the f.", and try again. Generally, in all shorts of SQLs, I've used AS keyword to create aliases.

Comment: You forgot the first part of the where clause.

Comment: Don't mind use exists or in. Don't use them a lot, but using them a little is OK. Current computers have enough power to do it. Using a join is also OK, but explanation seemmed more simple that way.

Comment: ahh. ok, now i'm getting results, but i'm getting the id of a user that definitely does not have an association record with post '88'. there are only 10 records in the `association_record` table, so i'm sure that the user should not be popping up in the results. and yes you can alias without the `AS` keyword.

Comment: i also only created four users, so basically i know exactly which users i should be getting from the query; but i'm not getting them

Comment: this query is going to be an essential query in the application logic. it will be used all the time for potentially millions of response records and following relationships. the query needs to be efficient

Comment: OK, I'll write a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Method 2: Using join

```
SELECT follower
FROM following, association_record
WHERE follower=user_id
  AND followee = 5
  AND post_id=88
  AND user_id = null;
```

Some SQL engines use != and some use <>. Try both if you have trouble.

Comment: that seems like it would give me the `association_records` that are not for post '88'

Comment: Think of a join like a cross table with combinations of both tables, We then limit both tables and make them match by some field. It should work.

Comment: Using distinct or unique before "follower" to reduce the results to one.

Comment: I believe it is DISTINCT

Comment: this isn't working how you think it's suppose to work. what it's doing is giving me a user id for every association record other than those linked to post '88'. in other words, i have 10 association records total associated with 3 different users. this query returns 7 results. so basically it's 10 minus the 3 response records that exist for post '88'. please read through my question again if you feel like you're unclear of what i'm asking, and let me know if you understand it. if not, i'll rewrite it

Comment: Did yoy modified the query using select DISTINCT follower ...?

Comment: you don't understand. even if the records resulting from that query were distinct, it wouldn't change the fact that the user ids that result from that query do not consist of just the user ids that are following '5' but have no association with post '88'. it contains the ids of all the users who are following 5 who have an association record with posts other than post '88'. do you see the difference? adding distinct to your results would only remove duplicates of user ids for users who have an association record with more than 1 post besides '88'

Comment: which means i would have a list of user ids for every user whose ever associated with a post that wasn't post '88'. i solved it myself anyways, so i'll post the answer when i have time

Comment: your updated answer doesn't work either. the solution is tricky. at least for me. i don't see why it works, but it does. like i said, i'll post the answer when i have time